# Найти общие даты в диапазонах дат (MomentJs)

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Использую momentjs. Мне необходимо найти общие даты в периодах дат. Периоды представлены в виде массива объектов

```
const period = [
  {
    start: moment("2019/1/12"),
    end: moment("2019/1/28")
  },
  {
    start: moment("2019/1/18"),
    end: moment("2019/2/12")
  },
  {
    start: moment("2019/2/1"),
    end: moment("2019/3/12")
  },
  ...rest
]
```

То есть необходимо найти пересечения этих диапазонов. Формат возвращаемых данных желателен в виде массива общих дат.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Тебе нужно пересечение всех периодов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно написать функцию которая проходит по датам и проверяет:

```js
function findCommonDates(periods) {
  // Создаем массив для хранения общих дат
  const commonDates = [];

  // Сортируем периоды по дате начала
  periods.sort((a, b) => a.start - b.start);

  // Итерируемся по периодам и ищем общие даты
  for (let i = 0; i < periods.length - 1; i++) {
    const currentPeriod = periods[i];
    const nextPeriod = periods[i + 1];

    // Если конец текущего периода больше или равен началу 
    // следующего периода, есть пересечение
    if (currentPeriod.end.isSameOrAfter(nextPeriod.start)) {
      const startDate = moment.max(currentPeriod.start, nextPeriod.start);
      const endDate = moment.min(currentPeriod.end, nextPeriod.end);
      commonDates.push({ start: startDate, end: endDate });
    }
  }

  return commonDates;
}

const period = [
  {
    start: moment("2019/1/12"),
    end: moment("2019/1/28")
  },
  {
    start: moment("2019/1/18"),
    end: moment("2019/2/12")
  },
  {
    start: moment("2019/2/1"),
    end: moment("2019/3/12")
  }
]

const commonDates = findCommonDates(period);
console.log(commonDates);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper
{
  max-height: 100vh !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Этот код сначала сортирует периоды по дате начала, а затем итерируется по ним, находя пересечения и добавляя их в массив commonDates. В результате выполнения этого кода, commonDates будет содержать массив объектов с общими датами.

Comment: Спасибо большое!)

Comment: @ЕвгенийМануйлов Пожалуйста :)